# Does received count always match send count for MPI message?

Tags: mpi

When you send one MPI message that consist of `n` elements of some `MPI_type` in one process and then receive in another with receive `count` being `> n` are you guaranteed to always receive all of the `n` elements?

In essence, if you send one message via blocking-mode `MPI_Send` and then receive it via one blocking-mode `MPI_Recv` with big enough receive buffer are you guaranteed to get the whole message?

Or is there a chance that you might get only fist `k < n` elements and should call `MPI_Recv` repeatedly until you get the whole thing.

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes but looking at both the official [documentation](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Recv.html) and [specification notes](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-1.1/node34.htm) I couldn't find a sure answer.

Comment: You cannot receive a truncated message in MPI

Comment: As Gilles says, you never get a truncated message, i.e. if n > count then MPI will report an error and fail. However, if n <= count then the receive will complete but in general you don't know what the value of "n" is (the size of the incoming message). You need to extract this from the status variable via a call to MPI_Get_count().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gilles and David said in comments, the answer is yes. As Gilles says, you never get a truncated message. If `n > count` then MPI will report an error and fail.

If `n <= count` then the `receive` will complete but in general you don't know what the value of `n` is (the size of the incoming message). You need to extract this from the status variable via a call to `MPI_Get_count()`.